# Add a total row to a Grouped Query

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to add a total row to a grouped query. The query I have is as below:

```
SELECT T3.[SlpName], T1.[CardCode], T1.[CardName], T1.[ShipToCode], T2.[ItemCode], T2.[Dscription], 
SUM(T2.[Quantity]) AS 'Total Quantity',
MAX(T2.[Price]) AS 'Line Price', 
SUM(T2.[LineTotal]) AS 'Line Total', 
SUM(T2.[GrssProfit]) AS 'Gross Profit' 
FROM OCRD T0 INNER JOIN OINV T1 ON T0.[CardCode] = T1.[CardCode] INNER JOIN INV1 T2 ON T1.[DocEntry] = T2.[DocEntry] INNER JOIN OSLP T3 ON T0.[SlpCode] = T3.[SlpCode]
WHERE T3.[SlpName] = 'Name' AND T1.[createdate] >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE())
GROUP BY T3.[SlpName], T1.[CardCode], T1.[CardName], T1.[ShipToCode], T2.[ItemCode], T2.[Dscription].
```

What I want is a total row for the SUM line - so in effect a sum of a sum.

I've tried adding a total using a Union clause but this gives me an error message. When I use the ROLLUP function it summarises each row instead of just the line I need the summary for. Can anyone help?

Many thanks.

Comment: What about `SUM(T2.[Quantity])  + SUM(T2.[LineTotal]) + SUM(T2.[GrssProfit])` ?

Comment: What is the error you get from the UNION query, and what was the code you tried?

Comment: I'd wrap this as a sub-select and do a CROSS APPLY at the end. ATTENTION: There's no guarantee, that your rows come up in the expected order.

Comment: Thought of a different approach, you'll find my exampel as answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a union without the group by mentioning the non sum columns as null, it shall work fine as follows:

```
SELECT  T3.[SlpName]
    ,   T1.[CardCode]
    ,   T1.[CardName]
    ,   T1.[ShipToCode]
    ,   T2.[ItemCode]
    ,   T2.[Dscription]
    ,   SUM(T2.[Quantity]) AS 'Total Quantity'
    ,   MAX(T2.[Price]) AS 'Line Price'
    ,   SUM(T2.[LineTotal]) AS 'Line Total'
    ,   SUM(T2.[GrssProfit]) AS 'Gross Profit' 
FROM OCRD T0 
INNER JOIN 
    OINV T1 
ON T0.[CardCode] = T1.[CardCode]
INNER JOIN
    INV1 T2
ON T1.[DocEntry] = T2.[DocEntry]
INNER JOIN OSLP T3
ON T0.[SlpCode] = T3.[SlpCode]
WHERE T3.[SlpName] = 'Name'
AND     T1.[createdate] >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE())
GROUP BY T3.[SlpName]
    ,   T1.[CardCode]
    ,   T1.[CardName]
    ,   T1.[ShipToCode]
    ,   T2.[ItemCode]
    ,   T2.[Dscription]
UNION
SELECT  NULL AS [SlpName]
    ,   NULL AS [CardCode]
    ,   NULL AS [CardName]
    ,   NULL AS [ShipToCode]
    ,   NULL AS [ItemCode]
    ,   NULL AS [Dscription]
    ,   SUM(T2.[Quantity]) AS 'Total Quantity'
    ,   NULL AS 'Line Price'
    ,   SUM(T2.[LineTotal]) AS 'Line Total'
    ,   SUM(T2.[GrssProfit]) AS 'Gross Profit' 
FROM OCRD T0 
INNER JOIN 
    OINV T1 
ON T0.[CardCode] = T1.[CardCode]
INNER JOIN
    INV1 T2
ON T1.[DocEntry] = T2.[DocEntry]
INNER JOIN OSLP T3
ON T0.[SlpCode] = T3.[SlpCode]
WHERE T3.[SlpName] = 'Name'
AND     T1.[createdate] >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE())
```

Comment: With a CTE it should get a better execution plan... And furthermore there is no guarantee that your TotalSum-row is coming up at the end of your result set...

Comment: This gives me exactly what I want and will be very useful for other queries as well. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this. But it completely untested - therefore no guarantee at all :-)

```
WITH mySums AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY T1.CardCode /*find your fitting order*/) AS PseudoIndex,
     T3.[SlpName], T1.[CardCode], T1.[CardName], T1.[ShipToCode], T2.[ItemCode], T2.[Dscription], 
    SUM(T2.[Quantity]) AS 'Total Quantity',
    MAX(T2.[Price]) AS 'Line Price', 
    SUM(T2.[LineTotal]) AS 'Line Total', 
    SUM(T2.[GrssProfit]) AS 'Gross Profit' 
    FROM OCRD T0 INNER JOIN OINV T1 ON T0.[CardCode] = T1.[CardCode] INNER JOIN INV1 T2 ON T1.[DocEntry] = T2.[DocEntry] INNER JOIN OSLP T3 ON T0.[SlpCode] = T3.[SlpCode]
    WHERE T3.[SlpName] = 'Name' AND T1.[createdate] >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE())
    GROUP BY T3.[SlpName], T1.[CardCode], T1.[CardName], T1.[ShipToCode], T2.[ItemCode], T2.[Dscription]
)
SELECT tbl.* FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM mySums
    UNION 
    SELECT 100000,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,SUM([Total Quantity]),SUM([Line Price]),SUM([Line Total]),SUM([Gross Profit])
    FROM mySums
) AS tbl
ORDER BY tbl.PseudoIndex
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried this out and it executes but returns no data.

Comment: Would be interested why, but nevertheless I'm glad you found a solution!